# Exception not being caught; System.FinalException: Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated

Tags: apex, exception, collection, iteration, try-catch

Why is this Exception not being caught?

I [read](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_statements.htm) that System.LimitException is not caught but didn't see anywhere about System.FinalException.

### Non-Working Code

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<RecordType> getRecordTypes() {

    try {

        String sObjectType = 'Task';

        List<RecordType> recordTypes = RecordTypeRepository.getBySObjectType(sObjectType);

        return removeGenericTaskRecordType(recordTypes);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        String message = ErrorMessage.formatExceptionMessage(e, 'There was an error running NewTaskFormController getRecordTypes.');
        System.debug(message);
        throw new AuraHandledException(message);
    }
}


public static List<RecordType> removeGenericTaskRecordType(List<RecordType> recordTypes) {

    RecordType genericTask = RecordTypeRepository.getById(RecordTypeRepository.GENERIC_TASK_ID);

    Integer genericTaskIndex = recordTypes.indexOf(genericTask);

    for (RecordType recordType: recordTypes) {
        recordTypes.remove(genericTaskIndex );
    }


    return recordTypes;
}
```

### What I've Tried

- The same code structure (try-catch) just a different exception and it does get caught.
  `"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: List index out of bounds: -1`

### Working-Code Example

```
 public static List<RecordType> removeGenericTaskRecordType(List<RecordType> recordTypes) {

    RecordType genericTask = RecordTypeRepository.getById(RecordTypeRepository.GENERIC_TASK_ID);

    Integer genericTaskIndex = -1;

    recordTypes.remove(genericTaskIndex);

    return recordTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception is not being caught because `FinalException` is not catchable. Neither are `LimitException` nor `AssertException`.

You can quickly check for yourself if a given type of exception is catchable using an anonymous script like the following:

```
try
{
    throw new FinalException();
}
catch (Exception pokemon)
{
    system.debug('Cannot catch em all');
}
```

Note that in general:

- you should know what specific types of exception you are expecting and catch only those
- it is better to avoid the exception entirely if it is preventable, even if it can be caught

Comment: It's also very avoidable; just using a normal for loop instead of for-each fixes the problem.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be a bit of a separate question though. *Why can I not catch `FinalException`* seems like one for which we might get plenty of dupes over the years.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kind of surprised this *is not* a duplicate (but apparently not?). Good to have an answer like this available.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason the [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_statements.htm) only mention `LimitException` and `AssertException` but not `FinalException`.

Comment: Yep makes sense. I was trying to find that link and include it but didn't have the time to do so. There may  be more than just these three types which are not catchable, but I am not aware of any others at this time.

Comment: The anonymous apex is useful, but would it prove that it's not being caught because it's a bug as opposed to because it's not catchable?

Comment: It does not prove the difference between those two, but in general, if a standard exception is not caught with this script, you can assume it is by design.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @Adrian is good, but on a different note the reason why you're getting this error was because your code attempts to modify a collection while it is being iterated in the **for each loop**, which is not allowed. Read about [Read-only Collections](http://peterknolle.com/collections-eggstravaganza/)

> If you need to modify the List or Set while iterating over it, use a
>   simple for loop with a counter instead of the Set or List iteration.

```
for (Integer i = accts.size()-1;  i>=0 ; i--) {
    Account a = accts[i];
}
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for suggestions. I should have looked more closely, I lifted off from the refered article. Fixed it now!

Comment: Thank you. I knew why I was getting the Exception and how to prevent it. I just wasn't sure if there was something wrong with my `try-catch`, if this was a Salesforce bug or as @AdrianLarson confirmed that all is good and it's the intended behavior.